# Ember: How do I inject into a view?

Tags: javascript, view, ember.js, dependency-injection

Suppose I have some reusable thing:

```js
App.FooUtil = Ember.Object.extend({
   foo: function () {
      return "bar";
   }
});
```

and then I register it like so:

```js
App.register('util:fooUtil', App.FooUtil);
```

And I try to "inject" it into my view:

```
App.inject('view', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
```

and now suppose I have this View:

```js
App.SuperView = Ember.View.extend({
   contextMenu: function(evt) {
      //This is ALWAYS undefined!
      var fooUtil = this.get('fooUtil');
      window.alert(fooUtil.foo());
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

```html
{{#view App.SuperView}}Right Click Me!{{/view}}
```

#### I can't inject the utility class into my view at all. What gives?

banging my head against a wall, I've also tried:

```
App.inject('views', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
App.inject('view:index', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
App.inject('view:topLevel', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
App.inject('view:super', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a downside to injecting `fooUtil` into all controllers? Then Your code would look like this:

```
App.SuperView = Ember.View.extend({
   contextMenu: function(evt) {
      var fooUtil = this.get('controller.fooUtil');
      window.alert(fooUtil.foo());
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Also where are you doing the injection?  I usually do it in an Initializer.

```
Ember.Application.initializer({

  name: 'fooUtil',
  after: 'store',

  initialize: function(container) {
    container.injection('controller', 'fooUtil', 'util:fooUtil');
  }
});
```

Comment: Not at all... But as a new Ember user, it was completely counter-intuitive to me that I'd have to inject something into the controller to access it in the view, when everything else seems much more targeted.

Comment: What are you specifically trying to do with the util?

Comment: Nothing important, it's a utility function that is used all over the place. There was just no intuitive way to inject it into a view, as far as I could see. ... Your answer worked. Thanks.